# Replicating sklearn.neural_network.MPLRegressor with Keras

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras

I'm currently working with sklearn.neural_network.MPLRegressor but looking for more fexibility in the definition of the neural network, I tried Keras.
I create the following dataset

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-0.5,5,2000)
y = np.tanh(x)
y=y.reshape(-1, )
x=x.reshape(-1, 1)
```

and implement the trivial neural network with sklearn

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
    model = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(1,),activation='tanh',solver='lbfgs',verbose=True,validation_fraction = 0.1) 
model.fit(x,y)
```

which is solved with a high degree of precision `MSE 7.252229995056021e-10`

I replicate the same nn with Keras

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model       
import keras
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor    
keras.initializers.RandomUniform()    
visible = Input(shape=(1,))
hidden1 = Dense(1, activation='tanh')(visible)    
output = Dense(1,activation="linear")(hidden1)    
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',metrics=['mean_squared_error'],loss =['mean_squared_error'] )
model.fit(x, y,validation_split=0.1)
```

but I obtain `MSE 0.02130996414874087` (the result doesn't change a lot using different optimizers).

Since the nn can be solved analytically, I would expect a higher degree of precision.
Does anyone know the reason behind such difference, if any (apart from the different optimizer)?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you need more epochs.  Then keras model will reach almost 0 loss for this data.  Other differences I can think of are batch size: default for sklearn is 200, keras uses 32; and the L2 regulation (sklearn uses `alpha=0.0001`).

Comment: It works!! Thanks!!